# Can solvePnP handle points outside of the Image-frame?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, pose-estimation, projection-matrix, opencv-solvepnp

Kontext: I have a soccer field, and I am building a Pipeline for Camera calibration (far from actual implementing). The camera is static and has an overview of the field. After some preparation I want to take the crossings of the field-lines to calculate the extrinsic Parameters of the camera with solvePnP. But sometimes the Camera-Image doesn't show the corners of the field which can easily be calculated. But can solvePnP handle these Points which are outside the field or is there another function which solves this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After trying on my own project, I can answer my own question with yes. OpenCVs solvePnP can handle coordinates outside the image without problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).